# How do I prompt for multiple Strings on open for my form?

Tags: vba, ms-access

In my Access DB, I made a form that asks for user input on open. The user can enter multiple itemIDs (numeric), seperated by comma, and the query returns a table with all the respective items.

My IDs now also contain letters (not my decision!), so I need to change the input type to String. Is there any way I can use the following linbes of VBA code to work just like they did before, but with Strings?

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim m As String

m = InputBox("Please enter itemIDs, seperated by commas", "itemID")
If m <> "" Then
      Me.Filter = "itemID in (" & m & ")"
      Me.FilterOn = True
Else
     Me.FilterOn = False
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks for the help! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Your code would work if you surround the filter by quotes. So:

```
   Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
   Dim m As String

   m = InputBox("Please enter itemIDs, seperated by commas", "itemID")
   If m <> "" Then
         Me.Filter = "itemID in ('" & m & "')" 'Notice the single quotes
         Me.FilterOn = True
   Else
         Me.FilterOn = False
   End If
   End Sub
```

However the trouble then becomes that multiple itemIDs will not be filtered properly, as you would need to surround them all by quotes. 
Like:

```
    Me.Filter = "itemID in ('ID001', 'ID002', 'etc')"
```

So you need to first add the extra quotes if the user input contains that pesky coma.
 
You could do something like:

```
   Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
   Dim m As String

   m = InputBox("Please enter itemIDs, seperated by commas", "itemID")
   If m <> "" Then
        'as a quick example, if m contains comas we surround them by quotes
         If InStr(1, m, ",") <> 0 Then m = Replace(m, ",", "','")
        'however this would only work if the user inputs the ids like "id1,id2"
        'it fails to account for a space after the comas like "id1, id2" 
         Me.Filter = "itemID in ('" & m & "')"
         Me.FilterOn = True
   Else
         Me.FilterOn = False
   End If

   End Sub
```

Hope this points you in the right direction!

Comment: Hey there!

This was exactly what I needed! Thank you so, so much! :)